# How to keep an image responsive and not effect other elements?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, positioning

I'm trying to include an image above text, however it affects the text if I resize that image. Whatever I try to do, either it losses responsiveness or moves text under the screen (I have one page 'body' with hidden overflow). I managed to move an image to the center of the screen both in height and width without it affecting the text below, but changing it's width makes it non responsive and moves other elements. Any help?

In short: I want that image above the text, bigger, responsive and not affecting the text.

```css
.pagr_foto {
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
   
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 64%;
    max-width: 70%; 
  }
  
  .icon {
    width:85px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 35%;      
}
.rows {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;   
    column-gap: 8px;
    margin-left: 5%; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
           <!--DIDELE FOTKE STARTS-->
    <div class="pagr_foto">
        <div class = "pagr_foto_remas">
            <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mate02trucha/_/rsrc/1472875957853/config/google_.jpg" class="pagr_foto_img"/>
        </div>

    </div>
   

      <!--DIDELE FOTKE ENDS-->
    <!--TEKSTAS PO APACIA STARTS-->
  <div class = "fadein"> <!--FADE IN ANIMACIJA-->
        <div class="container_text">
            <div class = "rows">
              
            <div class="feature">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"> 
                  <!--KAD ICONS BUTU VIRS TEKSTO-->
                <img src="assets/images/group.png" class="icon" />
                <h3>Watch or listen together</h3>
                <p>
                  Start a session and invite your friends by sharing your friend code with them.
                </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="feature">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"><!--KAD ICONS BUTU VIRS TEKSTO-->
                <img src="assets/images/list.png" class="icon" />
                <h3>Build up the queue</h3>
                <p>
                  Browse for your favorite media and add the URL to the queue. A number of popular websites are already supported for playback.
                </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="feature">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"><!--KAD ICONS BUTU VIRS TEKSTO-->
                <img src="assets/images/chat.png" class="icon" />
                <h3>Use enhanced features</h3>
                <p>
                  New features are added on top of streaming websites such as real-time chat and timestamp markers.
                </p>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

[image: How it looks right now]

[image: How I want it to be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you don't use Bootstrap instead of CSS3? Like this for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://sites.google.com/site/mate02trucha/_/rsrc/1472875957853/config/google_.jpg" class="pagr_foto_img"/>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
           <img class="img-fluid" src="https://estaticos.muyinteresante.es/media/cache/1140x_thumb/uploads/images/gallery/59c4f5655bafe82c692a7052/gato-marron_0.jpg" class="icon" />
            <h3>Watch or listen together</h3>
            <p>
              Start a session and invite your friends by sharing your friend code with them.
            </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dam.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/gatos-caja-2.png" class="icon" />
            <h3>Build up the queue</h3>
            <p>
              Browse for your favorite media and add the URL to the queue. A number of popular websites are already supported for playback.
            </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/640/cpsprodpb/10E9B/production/_109757296_gettyimages-1128004359.jpg" class="icon" />
            <h3>Use enhanced features</h3>
            <p>
              New features are added on top of streaming websites such as real-time chat and timestamp markers.
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually never used bootsrap for those purposes and I probably should. How could I make sure those images are centered?

Comment: Use Bootstrap, is very easy and not much complex like CSS3, more clean code, to make sure you can insert the image into the div and use a class text-center, like this for example. 

<div class="text-center">
  <img src="Here your link ">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving position absolute to .pagr_foto. And you didn't mention any css for image. By default image tag won't respect any other elements. So you have to mention style by your own.

```css
.pagr_foto {
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pagr_foto_img{
 width: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 64%;
    max-width: 70%; 
  }
  
  .icon {
    width:85px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 35%;      
}
.rows {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;   
    column-gap: 8px;
    margin-left: 5%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
           <!--DIDELE FOTKE STARTS-->
    <div class="pagr_foto">
        <div class = "pagr_foto_remas">
            <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mate02trucha/_/rsrc/1472875957853/config/google_.jpg" class="pagr_foto_img"/>
        </div>

    </div>
   

      <!--DIDELE FOTKE ENDS-->
    <!--TEKSTAS PO APACIA STARTS-->
  <div class = "fadein"> <!--FADE IN ANIMACIJA-->
        <div class="container_text">
            <div class = "rows">
              
            <div class="feature">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"> 
                  <!--KAD ICONS BUTU VIRS TEKSTO-->
                <img src="assets/images/group.png" class="icon" />
                <h3>Watch or listen together</h3>
                <p>
                  Start a session and invite your friends by sharing your friend code with them.
                </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="feature">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"><!--KAD ICONS BUTU VIRS TEKSTO-->
                <img src="assets/images/list.png" class="icon" />
                <h3>Build up the queue</h3>
                <p>
                  Browse for your favorite media and add the URL to the queue. A number of popular websites are already supported for playback.
                </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="feature">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"><!--KAD ICONS BUTU VIRS TEKSTO-->
                <img src="assets/images/chat.png" class="icon" />
                <h3>Use enhanced features</h3>
                <p>
                  New features are added on top of streaming websites such as real-time chat and timestamp markers.
                </p>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now my image position is great, however, if I change the hight of an image, it stops being responsive vertically. Should I just add media queries or resize the image itself, not in CSS?

Comment: Try removing height from pagr_fotto_img. if it not works go with media query.